# Set UDP checksum field (on net driver side)

Tags: udp, checksum

I have to change a net driver (on a real-time OS) to snif for a PTP frame (it's an UDP frame with special data field) and change some data. I need to update data in the net driver (R8168). Doing so I have to modify CRC field too, before sending the frame.
I've looked for some examples but no one works. I suppose that's something wrong in lines using htons or ntohs: I don't know if I have to use network byte order or host byte order.

```
unsigned int calc_checksum( unsigned char *pcBuf, unsigned short usLength, unsigned int uiSum )
{
    unsigned short i, usTmp ;
    /* Checksum all the pairs of bytes first... */
    for ( i = 0; i < (usLength & ~1U); i += 2 )
    {
        usTmp = *((unsigned short *)(pcBuf + i)) ;
        uiSum += (unsigned short)ntohs( usTmp ) ;
        if ( uiSum > 0xFFFF )
            uiSum -= 0xFFFF ;
    }
    /*
     * If there's a single byte left over, checksum it, too.
     * Network byte order is big-endian, so the remaining byte is
     * the high byte.
     */
    if ( i < usLength )
    {
        uiSum += pcBuf[i] << 8 ;
        if ( uiSum > 0xFFFF )
            uiSum -= 0xFFFF ;
    }
    /*.*/
    return uiSum ;
}

/* Recalculate UPD checksum */
usTmp = sizeof(TUdpHeader) + sizeof(TPTPSyncData) ;
uiSum = calc_checksum( (unsigned char *)(&pPTPFrame->udpHeader.sport),
    sizeof(TUdpHeader) + sizeof(TPTPSyncData),
    calc_checksum( (unsigned char *)(&pPTPFrame->ipHeader.saddr),
        2 * sizeof(unsigned int), IP_UDP + htons( usTmp ) ) ) ;
// Return the one's complement of sum
usTmp = (~uiSum) & 0xFFFF ;
pPTPFrame->udpHeader.checksum = htons( usTmp ) ;
```

Notes:

- pPTPFrame is a pointer to the full frame (EthHeader + IpHeader +
  UdpHeader + Data)
- IP_UDP = 17
- TPTPSyncData is the data structure

Thanks a lot.
Emanuele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct version:

```
/* Recalculate UPD checksum */
pPTPFrame->udpHeader.checksum = 0 ;
uiSum = calc_checksum( (unsigned char *)(&pPTPFrame->udpHeader.sport),
    sizeof(TUdpHeader) + sizeof(TPTPSyncData),
    calc_checksum( (unsigned char *)(&pPTPFrame->ipHeader.saddr),
        2 * sizeof(unsigned int), IP_UDP + sizeof(TUdpHeader) + sizeof(TPTPSyncData) ) ) ;
// Return the one's complement of sum
usTmp = (~uiSum) & 0xFFFF ;
pPTPFrame->udpHeader.checksum = htons( usTmp ) ;
```

Problem solved!